# Run a gsutil command in a Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I would like to run a gsutil command every x minutes as a cloud function. I tried the following:

```
# main.py
import os

def sync():
     line = "gsutil -m rsync -r gs://some_bucket/folder gs://other_bucket/other_folder"
     os.system(line)
```

While the Cloud Function gets triggered, the execution of the line does not work (or i.e. the files are not copied from one bucket to another). However, it does work fine when I run it locally in Pycharm or with cmd. What is the difference with cloud functions?

Comment: first you should check if `gsuitl` works (without running it Python) and later you can try to use `crontab` (instead of Python) to run it every X minutes - if you use Linux.

Comment: I tied to run it using os.popen and os.system, while this works fine in my local terminal, it doesn't trigger it in cloud function. I basically see a blank line and then it says that function executed completely. Seems more a gcf question, updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions server instances don't have gsutil installed.  It works on your local machine because you do have it installed and configured there.

I suggest trying to find a way to do what you want with the Cloud Storage SDK for python.  Or figure out how to deploy gsutil with your function and figure out how to configure and invoke it from your code, but that might be very difficult.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python) for this. You have very few change to perform in your code.

Create a container with gsutil installed and python also, for example `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk` as base image

Take care of the service account used when you deploy Cloud Run, grant the correct permission for accessing to your bucket

Let me know if you need more guidance

Comment: Hello @guillaume, do you have some sample DockerFile that can be used in for cloud run application using cloud-sdk as base image.

Comment: I have a sample here, where I install gcloud SDK on a base image: https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/serverless-sql/blob/main/serverless-sql/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

There's no straightforward option for that.

I think the best for Cloud Functions is to use `google-cloud-storage` [python library](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html)